# Macro stopped working after upgrading Microsoft Office

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am running some legacy VB6 applications with Access as our main tool for reports.

We are making the switch to Office 2016.

When I try to run a macro from my vb6 application I get an error stating that:

```
"2001 - You canceled the previous operation"
```

The error comes up on this code...

```
Acc.DoCmd.RunMacro "MarcoName"
```

I launched Access and clicked EnableContent. Then I went to Trust Center and marked it so that it "Doesn't show messages for blocked content". It doesn't do the trick. Although, if I use the code below, everything seems to run fine. So I think there is only an issue with RunMacro command which works on Office 2007.

```
Acc.DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryName", acViewNormal
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Access Options` -> `Trust Center` -> `Trust Center Settings` -> `Macro Settings` ->`**Enabled All Macros**`